# Xamarin Android Support V7 DrawerLayout and dynamic Toolbar/ActionBar buttons

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I am implementing DrawerLayout navigation based in the [NavDrawer](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar) example app from James Montemagno, but I want my Fragments that get loaded by the menu to be able to dynamically add action buttons to the Toolbar/ActionBar so they appear with the Hamburger icon that opens the menu.  I'm not sure how to do this or if it is possible.  How do I accomplish this?  Or is there a more appropriate approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JamesMontemagno on the Xamarin Forums for helping me answer this question.  Here is what I had to do to make it work:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/172433#Comment_172433

In the OnCreateView override of my Fragment, I needed to set the HasOptionsMenu property to true before calling the base method.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            HasOptionsMenu = true;
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            ...
        }
```

Then I had to override OnCreateOptionsMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected like so...

```
public override void OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        var filterActionItem = menu.Add(Menu.None, Resource.Id.toolbar_filter_action, Menu.None, new Java.Lang.String("Filter"));

        MenuItemCompat.SetShowAsAction(filterActionItem, MenuItemCompat.ShowAsActionIfRoom);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.toolbar_filter_action:
                Toast.MakeText(Context, "Selected Item: " + item.TitleFormatted, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                return true;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Note that I created an Ids.xml file to store my menu item id's like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <item name="toolbar_filter_action" type="id" />
</resources>
```

This allows me to reference the generated toolbar_filter_action id in the menu.Add(...) method. If you have multiple menu items that could be added by different fragments, then you'll want to store the Id's as a resource for easy reuse and for reference by the OnOptionsItemSelected override method to determine which menu/toolbar item was clicked.